# how to make my C# dll assembly contain comment text in the visual studio object browser?

Tags: c#

I found that system dll contain comment text if i open this assembly in visual studio object browser like this:
[image]
you can see, there is the comment text.
but my assembly not contain this, i have write comment text for these properties.
[image]
so i want to know, how to add this information for my dll aseembly?

Comment: Above the method declaration press '/' three times and fill in the template.

Answer (score 5):

This documentation is generated from blocks of [XML Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/xml-documentation-comments) (C# programming guide) that you write before class/method declarations.

Sample from above document:

> ```
> /// <summary>  
> ///  This class performs an important function.  
> /// </summary>  
> public class MyClass {}
> ```

If you're producing/packaging your assembly for others to use, it's important to know to turn on the XML documentation option in the project properties (Build page).

See [Documenting your code with XML comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc) (also on the Microsoft site) for a complete walkthrough.